# how to add an extra node in a circular linked list +java

Tags: java, collections, linked-list

Hi I'm new in data structure. I need an code to under stand the addition and deletion of a node in circular linked list in java. It'll be more good if you upload some picture to demonstrate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no circular linked list built into Java.  You'll have to write your own.

If your circular linked list implements the `java.util.List` interface, you'll do it like this:

```
List<String> circularList = new CircularLinkedList<String>();
circularList.add("foo");
circularList.add("bar");
circularList.add("baz");
circularList.remove("bar");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find it [on wikipedia, including an image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list#Inserting_a_node).
This one is for a doubly linked list. The former is for doubly linked lists but it is pretty similar for [singly linked lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Singly_linked_lists).

Being circular does not really matter here. The only difference is, that there are no special cases for inserting at beginning/end.

e: sorry for the broken links, fixed them.